# Installation of SAP crystal reports in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

The problem is i have installed sap run time engine for crystal reports in VS2010, yet i could not open the crystal report file in VS 2010. I Have no clue what the problem is. Is there any other file which i need to install except the run-time engine if so please notify and give me the link for it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need to reference the following DLLs when working wth CR in .NET:

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio and not just the runtime engine.